# Position results at the top if the regex matches the search term

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to rank search results, depending on whether the search term matches a url using regex in SQL

Example:

[image]

The results with the hostname.google.com I would like to position them at the top.

I'm testing in my query with this, but it doesn't give the expected result

```
ORDER BY url regexp \".*(http://|https://).*/$term/([0-9]{4,5})(?![0-9]).*\"
```

Answer (score 1):

For desired output you could use

```sql
order by url regexp 'https?://(\\w*\\.)*google\\.com' desc
```

It checks if `url` leads to domain `google.com` ore one of its subdomains, and if yes(1) orders higher then if no(0).

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVzSgQiu)